# How can I recreate a curlicue shape in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to use this element in a larger resolution poster:

[image]

I tried using Photoshop's free transform, but I lost too much quality. How can I create this shape?

Answer (score 5):

Select the pen tool and use it to trace over the image. You won't create pixels, but a path. Using the pen tool, create a path that exactly aligns with the image you want to trace. Then open up your "paths" windows, where your path will have appeared. Make sure you have a thin brush selected, and then select this path in the "paths" window.

Then, click the dashed circle at the bottom of the paths palette to stroke the selected path your selected brush.

Answer (score 1):

Tracing it out as a vector's the way to go. You can do this in illustrator (I find the pen tool much easier to work with in illustrator. Illustrator's also pretty much made for the pen tool.) and drag the shape over to Photoshop, or as Starkers mentioned, simply trace it with the pen tool directly in photoshop, then scale your path to the size you want and fill the path.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use pen tool and then press Enter button in the Keyboard.
2. Goto Paths and Select it.
3. Right Click the path with pen tool selected.
4. Give stroke path with brush selected.